# How to avoid of creating splash screen fragment when migrate to Single Activity architecture?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I try to migrate my app to Single Activity architecture with Navigation component.

In Multi Activity version when user run app, he gets into `SplashScreen` Activity, where app make some network operations(device registred, user checked,...). When all of this completed, he goes to content Activity.

In Single Activity version i must to create SplashScreen fragment to do same things, but i don't want to create it. This operations is too quick(~1s), i don't need fragment to it, now i want to make my content fragment(created from content Activity) like start destination fragment, and just to show loader on it while all "initial" network operation happens.

Seems like no problem situation, but the problem is i need to take my code from `SplashScreen` and put it into **content** Fragment, but it's not good place for it. Content fragment is too big, and it's recreating sometimes, so i need to create flags to show i don't want to run my "initial" operations again.

So how to do it with the best way? Or i need to create `SplashScreenFragment`?

My idea is to place this code on `MainActivity`, but i don't completle understand how to make it works. I need to show loader on content Fragment and somehow to create the situation, when "all begin works" only after initial code on `MainActivity` will finish.

Answer (score 0):

simplest way is create some helper class with callback. looks like

```
class fragmentContent{
  void onCreateView(){
    View view = ...; //show loader
    helper.doLongOperationInBackground(new Callback());
    return view;
  }

  class Callback{
    void onLongOperationComplete(){
      showViewContent();
    }
  }

}
```

do not forget to do long operation only once.